# How to Check whether the URL contains Id or not?

Tags: angularjs

Example : i want to check if url contains id then call abc() function otherwise call def() function.

in angularjs using mvc architecture.

Comment: Seems like you're looking for `$location` service of angularjs. Show more code please.

Comment: Where in the URL? In any case, all the URL components are available in the [`$location`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) service

Comment: if you are using ui-router which i would recommend you could check out the last few sections of this docu https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing

Comment: http://localhost:44444/index.html#/video1/id=123456  this link contains id and another like http://localhost:44444/index.html#/video1 then how i check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this.

```
var url = $location.absUrl();
    if(url.indexOf('id') !== -1){
        //call abc()
    }
```

**Or alternatively**

```
var url = $location.absUrl();
        if(url.indexOf('id') < 0){
            //call abc()
        }
```

Also inject $location in your controller.
Another option: Use window.location.href

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your URL like this

```
http://test.com/#/some/path?foo=bar
```

Then in your controller use

```
var searchObject = $location.search();
// {foo : 'bar'}
```

you can access **searchObject.foo**

In this way you can check your required conditions and do further processing.

Also inject **$location** in your controller